# How to update with laravel DB query with limit?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I need to use update database laravel query with limitation of rows to update.

I tried this, but this will update all rows and limit is ignored:

```
DB::table('threads as thr')
->join('replies as rep', 'rep.thread_id', '=', 'thr.id')
->where([
        ['rep.created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(30)],
        ['thr.closed','=',false]
 ])
 ->limit(10)
 ->update([ 'thr.closed' => true ]);
```

I need to limit results to update, not to change where conditions. I even tried **Thread::chunk(...)** and this will iterate through results in chunks but through all of them. With chunks I can use return false. But after call of chunk function it will iterate always again from the first item. In results for example chunking by 10 will iterate always only the first 10 items.

It is possible to limit it through this "DB::" notation or I need to choose another approach?

(I use PostgreSQL with Laravel DB conn.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911210/laravel-5-updating-single-row-limit-doesn't-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is working well:

```
 DB::table("threads")->whereIn('id', function ($query) {
        $query->from('threads as thr')
              ->join('replies as rep', 'rep.thread_id', '=', 'thr.id')
              ->select('thr.id')
              ->where([
                       ['rep.created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(30)],
                       ['thr.closed','=',false]
                   ])
              ->limit(1);
    })->update([ 'thr.closed' => true ]);
```

Answer found here: [Laravel 5 updating single row limit doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911210/laravel-5-updating-single-row-limit-doesn)'t-work

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like below

```
DB::table('threads as thr')
->join('replies as rep', 'rep.thread_id', '=', 'thr.id')
->where([
      ['rep.created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(30)],
      ['thr.closed','=',false]
])
->take(10)->update([ 'thr.closed' => true ]);
```

Comment: BadMethodCallException  : Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::update does not exist.

It seems the $threads is type of object laravel says ... but not have method update()..... it is like object with all DB data without reference....

Comment: as always... now 42 threads that fulfill whole condition were closed on the one query run ... ->take(10)->update([ 'thr.closed' => true ]); is not working

Comment: You can find your slove. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918972/eloquent-update-and-limit

Comment: I've already found here, thanks for help anyway:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911210/laravel-5-updating-single-row-limit-doesn't-work

Comment: You are most wellcome.